# IE6 text selection issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, selection

I am running into some weird problems with IE6 when I am trying to select text from the main div at http://mincovlaw.com/doc/canadacopyrightact. In IE6, I can only select the whole DIV at once, not line by line, like in other browsers.

No such problem exists in any IE7, FF3.6, Chrome 16 or Safari.

I did add some `user-select: none;`'s to a few divs on the page, but the same situation existed even before then.

Is there a *simple* fix to the problem? I would like to fix this for IE6 users, but not at the cost of revamping the whole layout.

Comment: You will soon come to realize that these problems aren't weird at all, and are in fact typical IE6 behavior.

Comment: The fact that your site works at all in IE6 is an achievement. IE6 is such a poor quality and out-of-date browser that you would be forgiven for not even bothering to test your site with it. The fact that it has bizarre quirks is well known, and there really is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

My advice?  Give up on IE6.  Don't support it.  IE6 is now less than 5% of the market (2% in some surveys).  It's not worth the effort to maintain it.

Comment: lol, strangely enough, IE6 is the only version of IE that I use on my computer when I want a non-tabbed browser, so I kind of want my websites to work in all of my browsers. But I do see your point.

Comment: @UnoMeinAme - i'm sorry, Why do you want a non-tabbed browser specifically?  You don't have to use tabs in a tabbed browser, and you can disable them if you like.

Comment: i know that :) I didn't say IE was the only browser i use, or even my main or default browser. It's just one of the browsers i use from time to time.

Comment: Using IE6 voluntarily these days is a sign of madness. Surely no-one would be that crazy?